# 12-hour AM/PM format to military (24-hour) time

Tags: c, arrays, string, time

I am trying to solve this task on hackerrank but having problem when submitting solution.

Here is my solution, I would like to someone point me to mistakes, or give me advice what to avoid when working with strings?

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

char clkType[3];
char hours[3];

char* timeConversion(char* s)
{
    strncpy(clkType, &s[8], 2);
    clkType[2] = '\0';

    if(strcmp(clkType, "AM") == 0)
    {
        s[8] = '\0';
        return s;
    }
    else
    {    
        s[0] += 0x1;
        s[1] += 0x2;
        s[8] = '\0';

        strncpy(hours, &s[0], 2);
        hours[2] = '\0';

        if(strcmp(hours, "24") == 0) 
        {
            s[0] = '0';
            s[1] = '0';
            s[8] = '\0';   
        }

        return s;
    }
}

int main() {
    char* s = (char *)malloc(512000 * sizeof(char));
    scanf("%s", s);
    int result_size;
    char* result = timeConversion(s);
    printf("%s\n", result);
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting expected result when I'm testing it with these 04:59:59AM, 12:40:22AM, 12:45:54PM, 12:00:00AM time cases but when submitting results it gives me errors on those test cases.

Comment: `clkType[3] = '\0';` --> `clkType[2] = '\0';`

Comment: BLUEPIXY corrected tnx, but results are the same.

Comment: Can you show a link to the task description?

Comment: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/time-conversion/

Comment: You add 12 hours by adding 1 or 2 to the digits. {'0', '9'} => {'1', '\x3a'}.

Comment: Do you know what time 12:40:22am or 12:45:54PM are in 24 hour notation? Unless you you figure out what the result should be, you cannot properly implementit.

Comment: Yes in AM, time stays the same, we just cut AM, and in PM we have to add 12 hours to those hours in PM time, and if that value is 24 we set it to 00?

Comment: NO! 12:34:56AM == 00:34:56; 12:34:56PM == 12:34:56

Comment: Basically I think that your logic is incorrect. As an example, I think that it is necessary to carry in case of carry at 9 pm.

Comment: dasblikenlight explained it clear, thanks all, i will correct it! :)

Comment: Isn't hackerrank a bit off with their AM and PM (Ante-meridium; before and Post-meridium, after)?

Comment: "Military time"? You mean standardized time format, as used by the whole world except for a few confused English-speaking countries?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show us what kind of debugging you've done.  I expect you to have run your [mcve] within Valgrind or a similar checker, and to have investigated with a debugger such as GDB, for example.  Ensure you've enabled a full set of compiler warnings, too.  What did the tools tell you, and what information are they missing?  And read Eric Lippert's [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Please read and understand [the question on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in C](/q/605845).  Also note that `sizeof (char)` is 1, by definition (`sizeof` returns the value in units of `char`).

Comment: Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have special handling for midnight. You need special handling for noon as well, and you need to fix midnight handling, too.

By convention, 12 AM denotes midnight and 12 PM denotes noon. Your code does it the other way around, converting 12:00:00 AM to 12:00:00 (noon) and 12:00:00 PM to midnight.

One simple way of dealing with time conversion problems is to convert the input to a number of seconds from midnight, and then format this number as the desired output. This approach eliminates character manipulation (adding 12 one digit at a time) and make the code more readable in general.

Comment: Yes, there is a confusion of that time format conversion, thanks for pointing that out! This solution advice is great and short.

Answer (score 1):

12 Am translates to `00:00:00` you return as soon as you check for `AM` you also need to check if it's 12